# what is "voting" linked to in text?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

I thought that very confusing for me to interpret:

"In a midday vote, Mr. McCarthy must win a majority of those present and voting to become speaker, leaving little room for Republican defections."

is "voting" refering to people capable to vote or is it the voting act?

like:

1 - the majority of people there capable of voting
or

2 - win the voting to became Speaker?

Comment: Take care with the tags.  Using both "British" and "American" is fairly pointless.  This isn't a question about "learning" so don't tag it.  Remember to look at the description of the tags.

Answer (score 2):

This is the language of the rules of the Senate.

> A majority of those present and voting.

There are 100 senators.  If 80 are present on a particular day (and 20 are absent for whatever reason). And if, of those 80, 10 decide to abstain and not vote.  Then there are 70 Senators present and voting.  To win a vote, McCarthy would need (in this example) more than 35 votes.

So "voting" here means "not abstaining".

It contrasts with "A majority of Senators" which would mean "more than 50" (regardless of how many are present or choose to abstain)